# Hide table view until all the data is loaded - IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to hide table view until all the data is loaded. I found this question:

[UITableView - hide all groups/cells while data is loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894520/uitableview-hide-all-groups-cells-while-data-is-loading)

They say about setting sections to 0 until all data is loaded, and then reload cells and table view, but they don't detail how to do it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can hide your table view

```
 [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
```

Until you get all your data and you make it visible

```
 [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
```